# Equivalent to Windows' Baretail

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line

Is there any alternative to Windows' [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/)?

What I am looking for is a graphical Baretail?
Actually, I don't really care that it is graphical but I want to be able to have colors (lines with ERROR in red, lines with WARNING in yellow and so on...)
And I want it to behave like a "perfect" `tail -f` command meaning that I want it to be non-invasive (does not prevent the file deletion).
But always on the watch (if a file is deleted, and recreated and re-written in it then the tool would just start showing it again).

In any case, any tool that does a better graphical interpretation of `tail -f` is welcome.

Comment: Added an up vote.  Hope that bumps this somehow.  I'm desperate for something OSX-native with the features of bare tail.

Answer (score 8):

[Multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/features.php)

Install with

```
brew install multitail
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I've been using "Console" as a general log viewer.  (Comes with the Mac as a system utility)

You can open up files and it'll act like tail but then also has filter abilities.  No color coding (that i'm aware of)...

Comment: Sadly console doesn't seem to be high performance in dealing with big files, whereas baretail on Windows handles it pretty well.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative, [Glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/download.html), and it is expected to  be released for Mac soon.

I couldn't find much more than this.

Comment: Yeah thanks.I guess I'm gonna have to stick with the good old tail -f in the Terminal :D

Comment: It's been two years and that page still says *"A Mac OS X version is also expected soon."* LOL.  At least it's open source, so this remains an answer for anybody willing to do some additional heavy lifting :)

Comment: I'm a huge fan of BareTail and have recently made the switch over to linux. For anyone that stumbles across this in the future it seems to be the closest thing to BareTail that I've found in my searches. It even has the regex matching for line highlighting and all that.

Answer (score 3):

While it does not do colorization, if you use `tail -F` (big F as opposed to little f), the tail activity will continue following a file if it's deleted and/or truncated and replaced with a new file of the same name.

Verbatim from the `tail(1)` man page:

-F
The -F option implies the -f option, but tail will also check to see if the file being followed has been renamed or rotated.  The file is closed and reopened when tail detects that the filename being read from has a new inode number.  The -F option is ignored if reading from standard input rather than a file.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but finally a more modern one is under development.  See [Tail Blazer](https://github.com/RolandPheasant/TailBlazer)

Disclaimer: this is an open source project and I am the developer

Comment: Upvoted as it does answer the question. However, please keep in mind it's a good Stackexchange custom to disclose an affiliation with a product recommendation to maintain a certain objectivity. Please state in your answer that you have developed this application. Thank you!

Comment: OMG! ...Mind Blown...

Comment: However, this seems to be a windows only software...

Comment: This site is about Mac, so I assume you mean to say non-Windows users should run and build this using Mono's .NET runtime? I don't think *nix and Mac can use chocolatey for getting the prebuilt .NET binary.